# npm install hanging due to possible incorrect url

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

When I run `npm install --verbose` The installation hangs at:

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/api/npm/wcp-cos-de-npm-virtual/chai-as-promised 1533ms
⸨  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadDep:tstest: sill pacote range manifest for chai-as-promised@^7.1.1 fetched in 1558ms
```

I pasted the url `ttps://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/api/npm/wcp-cos-de-npm-virtual/chai-as-promised` into my browser and was prompted with a login. Is it possible I have the wrong URL set? If not that what could be causing this to hang?

I also tried running `npm install --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ --verbose` but it hangs here:

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chai-as-promised 25ms (from cache)
⸨  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadDep:tstest: sill pacote range manifest for chai-as-promised@^7.1.1 fetched in 50ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate your npm client first.

See the heading `Authenticating the Npm Client` in this link
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry

Answer (score 0):

`npm config set loglevel info` and then `run npm i again`

then restart the system.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still getting this:

`npm http fetch GET 200 https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/api/npm/wcp-cos-de-npm-virtual/chai-as-promised 1533ms
⸨  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadDep:tstest: sill pacote range manifest for chai-as-promised@^7.1.1 fetched in 1558ms`

Comment: maybe u need to do authenticatio as mentioned by pkyo @runnerpaul